# XInputGetState hangs

Tags: c++, directx, xinput

I'm trying to use XInput API for my game engine (I'm using DirectX11 and C++). I just want to test if a controller is found so I #included  and call XInputGetState but I get a strange behavior:

```
    XINPUT_STATE state;
    ZeroMemory(&state, sizeof(XINPUT_STATE));

    DWORD result;
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < XUSER_MAX_COUNT; i++)
    {
        result = XInputGetState(i, &state);
        if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            ErrorBox(L"found controller on port ");
    }
```

if I connect a controller the program hangs and freezes, while if I disconnect the controller the game launches. If I step into the code with the debugger the result is that the controller is found and the message box is displayed. 
Why?

**EDIT**  the problem seems to be in the call to ErrorBox: this function just displays a Message Box using Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a performance hit when you check for a controller that wasn't attached last time you called it because it has to enumerate device, open driver connects, etc. Therefore, you are recommended to round-robin calls to check for new controllers. If you get `ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_CONNECTED` back, you shouldn't call `XInputGetState` again for that slot for a little while.  For an example of this, see [GamePad](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/GamePad.cpp) class in the *Directx Tool Ki* and the `ThrottleRetry` function.

In other words, the loop you wrote before is not a good idea to call every frame unless there are `XUSER_MAX_COUNT` controllers actually connected.

Comment: Yes, but if I comment out the  Errorbox it works fine. If I use a OutputDebugString it works fine. So what's the catch with the Win32 API call?

Comment: That problem is like in how your application handles the main window message loop, which you don't show here. For an example of how to do it for DirectX, see [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32/Main.cpp).